# Destination...not written because src files were empty?

Tags: json, gruntjs

I am using Grunt and receiving this particular error. Destination (_/_site/assets/js/script.js) not written because src files were empty.

Is there some kind of other log file somewhere?

This my package.json

```
{
 "name": "aortizRefresh",
 "author": "antonio ortiz <17antonio.ortiz@gmail.com>",
 "version" : "0.0.2",
 "homepage": "http://mmistakes.github.io/so-simple-theme/",
 "repository": {
 "type": "git",
 "url": "git://github.com/mmistakes/so-simple-theme.git"
 },
 "bugs": {
 "url": "https://github.com/mmistakes/so-simple-theme/issues"
 },
 "engines": {
 "node": ">= 0.10.0"
 },
 "dependencies": {
 "grunt": "~0.4.1",
 "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
 "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
 "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.2",
 "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.7.2",
 "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3",
 "grunt-recess": "~0.3.5",
 "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.2.0",
 "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0"
 }
}
```

And this is my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.initConfig({
      uglify:{
        my_target:{
        files: {
      '_/_site/assets/js/script.js' : ['_/assets/js/*.js', '_/assets/js/plugins/*.js', '_/assets/js/vendor/*.js']
      } //files
    } //my_target
  } //uglify
}) //initConfig
} //exports
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are the paths actually correct `'_/assets/js/*.js'`? Check to see if it's matching any files with `grunt uglify --verbose`.

Comment: Thanks Kyle! Turned out I was incorrectly adding some characters in front of the paths which did not belong. 
    `'_/_site/assets/js/script.js'` should actually be `'_site/assets/js/script.js'`

Comment: Thank you for reminder of my friend -v @KyleRobinsonYoung

Answer (score -1):

The above answers are appreciated,i got the same message as "Destination…not written because src files were empty?" . You could get this msg if you are not doing any mistake in file path etc.  
The reason is if you add any comments in between

```
src: 'js/jquery.js',//input file
dest: 'js/build/jquery.min.js' // output file
```

like above in gruntfile.js, 
pls don't add any comments to run your tasks successfully!